# Simple issues formatting trailing 0 with PHP

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to take a string like "2.4" and increment past 2.9 to 2.10, 2.11 and so fowarth. Please assist, been two days of searching! This is my last desperate attempt.

```
    $update =$note;// (float) $note; 
     for($x=1;$x<sizeof($index);$x++){

        if(preg_match("/\.9/s", $update)){
            $u = explode(".", $update);
            $update = number_format($u[0]+".10", 2);
        }else{
            $u = explode(".", $update);
            if(strlen($u[1])==2){
                $add + $u[2]+="1";
                $update = "{$u[0]}"."."."{$u[1]}{$add}";
            }else{
                $update += ".1";
            }
        }
        echo $update."\r";
     }
}
```

Comment: so you want to add .1 but when do you stop adding?

Comment: Yes, while retaining right padding 0's..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = "2.42";
$nums = explode(".", $string);

$whole = $nums[0];
$decimals = intval($nums[1]);

$add_times = 10;

for ($i = 0; $i < $add_times; $i++) {
    $decimals += 1;
    $final_num = floatval($whole . "." . $decimals);
    var_dump($final_num);
}
```

Comment: Negative. It comes int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
int(4)
int(5)
int(6)
int(7)
int(8)
int(9)
int(10)
0.1

Comment: ok, then place the concatenation inside the iteration. Try my updated code.